# Why does my model accuracy get stuck at ~32%?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Edit: I see someone downvoted this post, please let me know what I did so that I can avoid doing so in the future. Thanks

I am very new to deep learning, and I am working on my first non-tutorial based RNN model however I am getting very poor results.

I created a dataset of album reviews by Anthony Fantano with respective targets of scores between 1-9 ([here](https://github.com/98mprice/fantano-sentiment-analysis/blob/master/results.json)). My objective was to use sentiment analysis to predict a score based on the input text.

Firstly I am using the keras `Tokenizer` utility class to preprocess my raw text, then I pad/truncate the token-based text to a maximum size of `np.mean(num_tokens) + 2 * np.std(num_tokens)` and then I create an embedding vector (using the keras `Embedding` class)

I am using one-hot encoding on my target data, with a vector of length 10.

My network produces a length 10 vector with `softmax` activation, and I am using `categorical_crossentropy` as my loss function. I've chosen the unit sizes for my GRU cells (is this the correct terminology?) arbitrarily, but playing around with them has not produced better results for me.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding)
model.add(GRU(units=32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(GRU(units=16))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
optimizer = SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(x_pad, y_encoded,
          validation_split=0.05, epochs=5, batch_size=64)
```

Here is a summary of my network from keras

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
layer_embedding (Embedding)  (None, 2290, 8)           8000
_________________________________________________________________
gru_1 (GRU)                  (None, 2290, 32)          3936
_________________________________________________________________
gru_2 (GRU)                  (None, 16)                2352
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                170
=================================================================
Total params: 14,458
Trainable params: 14,458
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 259 samples, validate on 14 samples
```

My accuracy, at a learning rate of 0.01, always converges to 0.3166, but I am not sure why

```
259/259 [==============================] - 18s 68ms/step - loss: 2.2998 - acc: 0.2124 - val_loss: 2.2935 - val_acc: 0.4286
Epoch 2/10
259/259 [==============================] - 16s 63ms/step - loss: 2.2927 - acc: 0.2973 - val_loss: 2.2854 - val_acc: 0.3571
Epoch 3/10
259/259 [==============================] - 16s 61ms/step - loss: 2.2822 - acc: 0.2471 - val_loss: 2.2767 - val_acc: 0.3571
Epoch 4/10
259/259 [==============================] - 15s 58ms/step - loss: 2.2728 - acc: 0.2973 - val_loss: 2.2681 - val_acc: 0.4286
Epoch 5/10
259/259 [==============================] - 15s 58ms/step - loss: 2.2651 - acc: 0.3166 - val_loss: 2.2575 - val_acc: 0.4286
Epoch 6/10
259/259 [==============================] - 15s 58ms/step - loss: 2.2548 - acc: 0.3166 - val_loss: 2.2496 - val_acc: 0.4286
Epoch 7/10
259/259 [==============================] - 15s 57ms/step - loss: 2.2469 - acc: 0.3166 - val_loss: 2.2420 - val_acc: 0.4286
Epoch 8/10
259/259 [==============================] - 15s 58ms/step - loss: 2.2382 - acc: 0.3166 - val_loss: 2.2325 - val_acc: 0.4286
Epoch 9/10
259/259 [==============================] - 15s 58ms/step - loss: 2.2305 - acc: 0.3166 - val_loss: 2.2265 - val_acc: 0.4286
Epoch 10/10
259/259 [==============================] - 15s 58ms/step - loss: 2.2222 - acc: 0.3166 - val_loss: 2.2158 - val_acc: 0.4286
```

There are 2 possible causes that I can think of, the 1st being that my learning rate is too large (since the accuracy seems to jump, indicating an overshoot). I have tried lowering it all the way to 0.05 but after 20 epochs my accuracy could not pass 0.2046. I have also tried using both Stochastic Gradient Descent and Adam optimisers but neither has produced vastly different results.

The other possible cause I could think of was that my dataset was too small (at only 259 samples) but I am not even able to get a high accuracy from overfitting so I assume this is not the issue? Also, my actual feature data (the raw text) is very large and extensive.

If it is of any assistance, my full source code file is available [here](https://github.com/98mprice/fantano-sentiment-analysis/blob/master/rnn.py).

Any help would be much appreciated, whether it is a point in the right direction or a correction of my understanding somewhere. Thanks

Comment: Try using `mask_zero=True` for embedding and pad sequences post instead of pre. Otherwise it looks like you need to modify hyperparameters, embedding of 8 might be too small.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I added `mask_zero=True` and played around with a larger embedding size (up to 20), but neither had a noticeable effect (accuracy still gets stuck at 0.3166). I also changed the padding to `post`, but it actually worsened the accuracy (I'm not sure why). The hyperparameters I have messed with so far is the learning_rate, number of hidden layers and also the batch size, but I haven't been able to get better results with any of these yet. Do you have any other suggestions for hyperparameters to change? Thanks

Comment: It's not the accuracy that should be monitored solely. Primarily, we're interested in reducing the training loss which was steadily (albeit suspiciously slowly) dropping in you case. I haven't worked on embedding layers, but do you not need to put `timesteps` somewhere in you code? In case the loss does not drop even after say 100 epochs, then something is horribly wrong with your code. Choice of optimizer can't cause this. With ~259 samples it should have overfit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that you are mistreating your dataset. You have reviews on a scale from 1 to 9, and even though this not a continuous range, it is characterized by a **strict total order** which you are not utilizing. To make my point clearer, if your algorithm predicts that a review is assigned a score of 8, with the true label being 9, then it may be wrong but it's only slightly so. On the other hand, if it made a prediction of 1, it would be way off. Your current system has no means of making that distinction, as you are treating all 10 discrete classes as equally remote from one another. My suggestion would be to switch the objective function to MSE, despite the discrete nature of your data, and use a wrapper to measure the accuracy. This should definitely help training, and you can switch back to Cross-Entropy later on.

Disclaimer: I haven't read through your code, but I've had similar problems quite often and I've been able to solve them the way I described.

Comment: Thank you, you make an excellent point. I will modify my code and see if I can improve it.

Comment: Give it a shot and report on how it goes ;)

Comment: haha, I am now getting 100% accuracy ~ so I'm probably overfitting but I guess that's to be expected considering the small dataset. Anyway, I think my previous issue is resolved so I'll accept your answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Konstantinos is absolutely correct - because the result is a numbered result that measures an amount of something (in this case a review), you want to use MSE, and make sure that the model is treating the numbers as a "scale", instead of individual classes. You would use individual classes if you were, per se, identifying a genre of music (Pop, Hip Hop, Rock, etc.), but in this case, there's a degree of "goodness" (9 being very good, and 1 being not good). Usually, any type of rating problem needs to use this "MSE-scaled" system.

A prime example of where this is used is in the model/algorithm in my book about DL and Stock Prediction, which you can read more about [here](https://www.energize.ai/stockprediction/). It uses a Deep Learning model to rate a stock (also known as a "Buy Rating").

Good Luck!